# Is Cassandra not suitable for the task or I'm misunderstanding documentation?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I was planning to substitute Oracle SQL on this task:

-several billions rows (n * 1000 millions)

-100% operations are simple selects

but there are 10 different criteria for selecting data. And they are combined also. E.g.

```
search1 - "select ... where name = 'x' and birth = 'y'"
search2 - "select ... where name = 'x' and phone = 'y'"
```

et c

Surprisingly, found that it is a huge pain to make such queries in Cassandra.
Especially, concerning 2 billion cell limit and that we do not plan huge cluster. At first it will work on 1 server, so this division to partitions will bring no profit, but will need time to overcome.

So, the questions are:

-will one (or maybe two, if Oracle also will be slow) server with Cassandra be dramatically faster than one RDBMS server?

-does right (not ugly) data model for my task exist or it is simply not for Cassandra?

-maybe other NOSQL database will suit much better?

Comment: Cassandras main strength is horizontal scalability, i.e. data distribution and parallelization. If you have just one or two nodes, you are not playing to that strength, and an RDBMS is a better fit. This is not really a good SO question, though, so I am voting to close.

Comment: I totally disagree. Question 1: the fact that 8 node Cassandra will rip apart RDBMS doesn't mean that on 1-2 nodes it will not be faster twice or treble. Remember, I do not need ACID. Question 2: it is not common question - how should I divide my data to fit to cassandra's 2B limit. Should I create around 100 tables to contain several billions of rows with 10 searchable criteria? What is the common strategy for such division?

Comment: The 2B Cell limit is per Partition (each node is responsible many many partitions), your partitions also should probably be less than ~100MB large as well so thinking about 2B is probably well beyond what you should realistically do in practice anyway.

Commonly when people use C* they have duplicated data in tables using different primary keys to service different queries.

Comment: I still do not understand how to store billions of records with Cassandra. My search criteria are combined to groups, so I must create around 10 different tables each having 2 or 3 primary keys. Is it OK for Cassandra data model? And also - how can I split partitions to 100MB if I should have billions of rows in every table? Make tables like table_search_by_name_and_birth_name_starts_aa, table_search_by_name_and_birth_name_starts_ab, table_search_by_name_and_birth_name_starts_ac ??? That looks terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra CQL is not very good for doing table scans or ad hoc queries.

Cassandra CQL works best when you are doing transactional queries that target either one row or a set of clustered rows (within a partition).

So in your example, Cassandra would work if you wanted to partition the data by name, and then work on one name at a time. This would scale to billions of names by adding more nodes.

But then if you want to search all names for particular selection criteria, then it's a table scan and you'd have to pair Cassandra with something like spark to have that be efficient.

So for your use case you are probably better off with a relational database than Cassandra. If you wanted to use Cassandra you'd probably need to create several tables with duplicated data, where each table used a key designed for to work for one or two of your different query types.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear how can I "partition the data by name". Thinking in RDBMS terms I have row with 10 columns (firstName, lastName, birth, address, phone, etc) and I must be able to search by: name+phone OR lastName+firstName+birth OR lastName+firstName+addr. Searches will often return only 1 record. Is it OK to add all 10 columns to primary key? So the limit for table will be 200mln rows? And to store several billions of records I should create dozens of tables? But whats the strategy for separation? Should I implement this separation algorithm in application (which makes searches) also?

Comment: I think you need to do some background reading on the meaning of partition keys and clustering keys in Cassandra. You're trying to use a relational approach in a partitioned key value store database, and that's not going to work. The data modeling in Cassandra is a very different beast and it doesn't support the kind of table scans and ad hoc queries you want to do. So you might want to check out some of the tutorial videos on the Datastax Academy website since it's a pretty complex subject.

Comment: OK, I'll try to find something. Spent all today reading, about C* data model and limitations, but everything I've found was simple use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

Further searching showed that MongoDB suits perfectly for the task and is about 10 times faster than Oracle SQL.